# Mysql string with all groups

Tags: mysql, sql

It's a bit of a non-descriptive title, but I'm not sure how to describe this in one sentence.
I've designed a MySQL database containing three tables.
Simplified, they look like this:

> ### MenuItem
>
> ID INT
> Desc TEXT

> ### Groups
>
> ID INT
> Desc TEXT

> ### ItemPerGroup
>
> ID INT
> ItemID INT
> GroupID INT

The ItemPerGroup table contains a list of items and the groups they belong to. An item can belong to multiple groups.
I would like a query that gives me all the MenuItems (Desc) and a string of all the groups the item belongs to (like: "Group1, Group2, Group3")

Is this possible and how to get there? Any pointers/directions are appreciated

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks, didn't know that one. Ike already explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Something like this:

```
 select MenuItem.Desc, group_concat(distinct Groups.Desc)
 from ItemPerGroup
   inner join MenuItem on MenuItem.ID = ItemPerGroup.ItemID
   inner join Groups on Groups.ID = ItemPerGroup.GroupID
 group by MenuItem.Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining all three tables, something like:

```
SELECT m.Id, GROUP_CONCAT(`g.Desc` separated by ',')
FROM MenuItem m INNER JOIN ItemPerGroup i
ON m.Id = i.groupId
INNER JOIN Groups i
ON m.Id = i.itemId
GROUP BY m.Id
```